# Ubuntu 18.04 fails to authenticate after first attempt

Tags: login, 18.04, authentication, bug-reporting

If I mistakenly type my password incorrectly,
then Ubuntu shows message to say **unable to authenticate**,
and then even if I enter **correct password**,
it just shows a blank purple screen and doesn't take me to the Ubuntu Desktop.
The only option is to restart the computer by press and holding power button.

What could be a possible cause?
How do I overcome this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Click the gear next to `Sign In` button and ensure right desktop is selected. The wrong ones (there can be five) can generate purple screen.

Comment: Ubuntu (Xorg) and Ubuntu Wayland available, I am using Xorg